# Angular 4 cannot used data from http post response to highchart

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I was trying to put my data from response Http Post to data series in Highchart, this is what I am trying to do..

simplechart.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

interface UserResponse {
    login: string,
    bio: string,
    company: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simplechart',
  templateUrl: './simplechart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simplechart.component.css']
})
export class SimplechartComponent implements OnInit {

    // chart = new Chart({
  //     chart: {
  //       type: 'line'
  //     },
  //     title: {
  //       text: 'Linechart'
  //     },
  //     credits: {
  //       enabled: false
  //     },
  //     series: [{
  //       name: 'Line 1',
  //       data: [10, 20, 30,40,50]
  //     }]
  //   });
  //
  //    add() {
  //   this.chart.addPoint(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  // }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
  ngOnInit() :void{
    this.http.get<UserResponse>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe(
        data => {
        console.log("User Login: " +data.login);
        console.log("Bio: " +data.bio);
        console.log("Company: " +data.company);
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error){
            console.log("Client-side Error occured");
        } else {
            console.log("Server-side Error occured");
        }
    })
    const body = {};
    const req = this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5004/meta/pushnotiflogevent',body,{
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      var chart: any;
      //var datas: any[] = [];
      var appid: any[] = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
           datas.push(data['data'][i]['count']);
         }

      for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
          appid.push(data['data'][i]['application_id']);
         }

         chart = new Chart({
             chart: {
               type: 'line'
             },
             title: {
               text: 'Linechart'
             },
             credits: {
               enabled: false
             },
             series: [{
                   name: 'appid',
                   data: datas
                   //data : (
                    // function () {
                    //   var data: any[] = [];

                    //   for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
                    //       data.push(data['data'][i]['application_id']);
                    //      }
                    //      return data;
                    // }
                   //)
                 }]
               });

           //    add() {
           //   this.chart.addPoint(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
           // }

      console.log(datas);
      console.log(appid);
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error occured");
    })

  }

}
```

simplechart.component.html:

```
<div [chart]="chart"></div>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SimplechartComponent } from './components/chart-demo/simplechart/simplechart.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SimplechartComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "charts",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular-highcharts": "^3.4.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.14",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.3.0.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "author": ""
}
```

That's the code. 
I am trying to do some simple showing Highchart using data from Http Post Response, why doesn't it work? Is there something I am missing?

now the layout for highchart already show, but the value not. how to show the value?

[Highchart show but not the value (Check the picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z68vH.png)

Comment: The static chart commented in the top works fine?

Comment: Yeah that's working fine, but if i used the same code but i moved inside .subscribe part ( looks the code above ). it won't show the chart on html view

Comment: Try what i suggested in my post

Comment: wow (chart:any;) really fix the issue. 
now my blank chart is shown, but the value is still not there. why? 
i will reply this an hour later because i m going to home.

the value i want to show is count, appid is the name which count is it.

Array Count [ "28", "268", "94925", "22", "15437", "223", "9", "2", "3136" ]  simplechart.component.ts:102:6
Array Appid [ "d22456e4-6d0e-11e7-950f-6562697a7534", "ecedb2f4-774a-11e7-a57d-6562697a7534", ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the chart variable outside the subscribe function:

```
export class SimplechartComponent implements OnInit {
chart:any; //need to declare it here first so you can use it in your template
/...

//in your subscribe function fill your chart variable without redeclaring it.
/...
var datas:any[]=[];
for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
       datas.push(+data['data'][i]['count']);
     }
/...
this.chart = new Chart({
             chart: {
               type: 'line'
             },
             title: {
               text: 'Linechart'
             },
             credits: {
               enabled: false
             },
             xAxis: {
                   categories: appid
             },
             series: [{
                   name: 'appid',
                   data: datas //the array used in your code
                 }]
               });
```